# Window Service Start Failure in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a windows service application. When I press the button, I want to start the service. But I'm receiving the following the error.

> Window Service Start Failure:
>        Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A Windows
>        Service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started
>        with the ServerExplorer, Windows Service Administrative tool or the NET
>        START command.

C# Code:

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
  partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
 {
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        RegistryKey KEY = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\baslat", true);
        KEY.DeleteValue("timer",true);
    }
    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        RegistryKey KEY = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\baslat", true);
        KEY.SetValue("timer","");
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message told you to do? Use `installutil` to install the service, then start it either through the service control panel, or by executing a `net start NAME` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you what to do. You need to install the service inside windows. Then you can stop and start it using the windows [service control manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can't start it like an exe as services have different entry points. However there is nothing stopping you from having an exe that runs under the SCM and as a normal program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the service, as the error message suggest :

```
installutil.exe yourservice.exe
```

Then you can start it with :

```
net start yourservice
```